# angular 2 on selected option

Tags: angular, typescript

I have code for my `HTML`

```
<select [(ngModel)]="empfile.storeno"  class="form-control">
    <option *ngFor="let p of concept" [ngValue]="p.MAP_Code">{{p.MAP_Code}}</option>
</select>
```

And my `component`

```
public concept = [];
public datakartu: any = {cardno:""};
public empfile : any = {fullname:"",nik:"",disclimit:"",birthday:"",email:"",storeno:""};

constructor(
    private _router: Router,
    private _httpprovider: Httpprovider
) {}

ngOnInit() {

}

cardnof(newValue) {
    this.datakartu.cardno = newValue
    this._httpprovider.httpReq('http://192.168.1.40:5000/getdataemp','POST',{cardno:newValue},null).subscribe((data)=> { 
        var rData = [];
        for (let i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
            rData.push(data[i]);
        }

        var store = rData.map(i=>(i.Store_ID)).toString();

        this.empfile.storeno = store; << for changing the display on the combobox

console.log(this.empfile.storeno); << here i put the console log
    });
}
```

I add `this.empfile.storeno = store;` so that it will change the display of the combobox to be what is we get from database,
but it just show blank.

But when I do `console.log()`, the value is there, just the string doesnot show up on the screen.[image]

basicly what i do is fill the card no then all the other fields will be fill in with data from database but the combo box doesnot display anything, but when i do console log it show value

[image]

this is what result if i do console log of

```
this.empfile.storeno = store;
```

Comment: Guess the "construcotr" mistake is not present in your code?

Comment: well thats not the case, i misstype here

Comment: Does this.concept contain store value?

Comment: yes it is, thats on diferent function and its working fine, my problem is when i get value in string and i want to pass it to the combo box so on the user interface it display it for the user

Comment: Note that `store` is a string of the form `"1,2,3"` if `rData.length>1`

Comment: please have a look again of what console log of store

Comment: please show where you put your `console.log`, that does not mean anything if you put it at the wrong place.

Comment: if you remove `[(ngModel)]="empfile.storeno"` does it works?. this `map` generate a string of numbers separated by comma...and you're use this value as `selectedValue`...sounds weird for me.

Comment: it doesnot work if i remove it, cause i need it to send value.

Comment: I was asking about the `select`, not the solution. It would be interesting to find out what is the source of your problem...as you said that your `concept` works, it should show the select options filled...if the options were shown without `[(ngModel)]="empfile.storeno"` you'll identify the source of your problem (that I'm quite sure that is the `empfile.storeno`)

Comment: im adding storeno to empfile array, or maybe should i discard it from empfile and create another array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For changing the display on combobox, you have to set [(ngModel)] to an **object**, instead of just setting it to one of the properties of the object.
A different object or literal, even with the same value does not work. It has to be an object from the same collection.

```js
var store = rData.map(i=>(i.Store_ID)).toString();

var filteredValues = concept.filter(i => i.MAP_Code === store);
 
if(filteredValues.length > 0) {
   this.empfile = filteredValues[0];
}
```

and in the html set ngModel to empfile

```
<select [(ngModel)]="empfile"  class="form-control">
    <option *ngFor="let p of concept" [ngValue]="p">{{p.MAP_Code}}</option>
</select>
```

This is assuming, "concept" is an array of objects of type *any*, which can be set to empfile.

Comment: well that doesnot work, in my rData there is another object also, such as full_name, bithday , etc

Comment: so what object type is "concept" array made up of? Is the concept array filled?

Comment: {MAP_Code:"000"} like that

Comment: I am not sure how `rData.map(i=>(i.Store_ID)).toString();` returns `000` as seen in your console. But if it returns `000`, `concept.filter(i => i.MAP_Code === store);` should return array of items from concept array with MAP_Code 000. Setting ngModel to first item from the returned array should work. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: it still not change, can you create a simple plunker code, with combobox (selected option with *ngFor) and an input text box that will change the display of combobox when the text is change, maybe my code is wrong here

Comment: maybe the problem is setting ngValue to `p.MAP_Code`. ngValue should be also set to complete object, instead of one of the properties of object. Please refer the working plunker at [link]http://plnkr.co/edit/8p4STI6vUMSk3FTkTHKu?p=preview, in case if it still does not work.

Comment: Setting ngValue to `p` should work. I have edited the answer.

Comment: i guess there is something wrong with my var store = rData.map(i=>(i.Store_ID)).toString(); which i got it from database, its become 000 but when im not put toString() in it, its become ["000"]

Comment: im sorry man, im the one wrong here, its 000 with space in the back thats why its not showing up in the display, my data is not valid not my code thx for the help